# contar filas de una misma columna y mostrar los resultados en dos columnas distintas

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Me gustaría contar valores dentro de una misma columna y que el resultado se muestre en dos columnas distintas:

```
Dia         estado
Lunes       false
Lunes       true
Martes      false
Martes      true
Miércoles   true
Miercoles   true
Viernes     false
Viernes     true
```

Y estoy buscando que me quede asi:

```
Dia        false    true
Lunes       1         1
Martes      1         1
Miercoles   0         2
Viernes     1         1
```

Seguramente es muy facil pero no encuentro el codigo correcto, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realiza la siguiente consulta para obtener el resultado;

```
SELECT dia, COUNT(IIF(estado=0,estado,NULL)) AS false, COUNT(IIF(estado=1,estado,NULL)) AS true 
FROM BD.dbo.table 
GROUP BY dia
```